# Tensorflow Datasets with string inputs do not preserve data type

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

All **reproducible** code below is run at Google Colab with TF 2.2.0-rc2.

Adapting the simple example from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) for creating a dataset from a simple Python list:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
# '2.2.0-rc2'
np.version.version
# '1.18.2'

dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3]) 
for element in dataset1: 
  print(element) 
  print(type(element.numpy()))
```

we get the result

```
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
<class 'numpy.int32'>
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
<class 'numpy.int32'>
tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int32)
<class 'numpy.int32'>
```

where all data types are `int32`, as expected.

But changing this simple example to feed a list of strings instead of integers:

```
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(['1', '2', '3']) 
for element in dataset2: 
  print(element) 
  print(type(element.numpy()))
```

gives the result

```
tf.Tensor(b'1', shape=(), dtype=string)
<class 'bytes'>
tf.Tensor(b'2', shape=(), dtype=string)
<class 'bytes'>
tf.Tensor(b'3', shape=(), dtype=string)
<class 'bytes'>
```

where, surprisingly, and despite the tensors themselves being of `dtype=string`, their evaluations are of type `bytes`.

This behavior is not confined to the `.from_tensor_slices` method; here is the situation with [`.list_files`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#list_files) (the following snippet runs straightforward in a fresh Colab notebook):

```
disc_data = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('sample_data/*.csv') # 4 csv files
for element in disc_data: 
  print(element) 
  print(type(element.numpy()))
```

the result being:

```
tf.Tensor(b'sample_data/california_housing_test.csv', shape=(), dtype=string)
<class 'bytes'>
tf.Tensor(b'sample_data/mnist_train_small.csv', shape=(), dtype=string)
<class 'bytes'>
tf.Tensor(b'sample_data/california_housing_train.csv', shape=(), dtype=string)
<class 'bytes'>
tf.Tensor(b'sample_data/mnist_test.csv', shape=(), dtype=string)
<class 'bytes'>
```

where again, the file names in the evaluated tensors are returned as `bytes`, instead of `string`, despite that the tensors themselves are of `dtype=string`.

Similar behavior is observed also with the `.from_generator` method (not shown here).

A final demonstration: as shown in the `.as_numpy_iterator` method [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#as_numpy_iterator), the following equality condition is evaluated as `True`:

```
dataset3 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'a': ([1, 2], [3, 4]), 
                                               'b': [5, 6]}) 

list(dataset3.as_numpy_iterator()) == [{'a': (1, 3), 'b': 5}, 
                                       {'a': (2, 4), 'b': 6}] 
# True
```

but if we change the elements of `b` to be strings, the equality condition is now surprisingly evaluated as `False`!

```
dataset4 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'a': ([1, 2], [3, 4]), 
                                               'b': ['5', '6']})   # change elements of b to strings

list(dataset4.as_numpy_iterator()) == [{'a': (1, 3), 'b': '5'},   # here
                                       {'a': (2, 4), 'b': '6'}]   # also
# False
```

probably due to the different data types, since the values themselves are evidently identical.

---

I didn't stumble upon this behavior by academic experimentation; I am trying to pass my data to TF Datasets using custom functions that read pairs of files from the disk of the form

```
f = ['filename1', 'filename2']
```

which custom functions work perfectly well on their own, but mapped through TF Datasets give

```
RuntimeError: not a string
```

which, after this digging, seems at least not unexplained, if the returned data types are indeed `bytes` and not `string`.

So, is this a bug (as it seems), or am I missing something here?

Comment: I've stumbled upon similar problem where I am using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list_of_paths).interleave(). How did you customize it and can it still be parallelized? Check out this questions I've posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76896959/tensorflow-tf-data-dataset-interleave-outputs-invalidargumenterror-typeerror

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known behavior:

From: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5552#issuecomment-260455136

> TensorFlow converts str to bytes in most places, including sess.run, and this is unlikely to change. The user is free to convert back, but unfortunately it's too large a change to add a unicode dtype to the core. Closing as won't fix for now.

I guess nothing changed with TensorFlow 2.x - there are still places in which strings are converted to bytes and you have to take care of this manually.

From the [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38409) you have opened yourself, it would seem that they treat the subject as a problem of Numpy, and not of Tensorflow itself.